# What is the difference between IntegratedWindowsAuthentication vs Negotiate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, owin

When setting up my owin self hosted projected I want to set it up to use authentication using windows domain. As I understand this is performed through a negotiate protocol where it tries Kerberos and fails back to NTLM if unavailable. I looked online and the code snippet looks like this

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpListener listener =
       (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
    listener.AuthenticationSchemes =
        AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
   ...
}
```

While there I discovered the `AuthenticationSchemas` enum. The enum is a flag enum but I'm trying to undestand what is the difference between Integrated windows and negotiate? Both seem to do the same thing of providing Kerberos and a failback to NTLM. Why would I use one or the other? The documentation is not very helpful on the matter.

Answer (score 4):

The enum is defined as:

```
[System.Flags]
public enum AuthenticationSchemes
{
    None = 0,
    Digest = 1,
    Negotiate = 2,
    Ntlm = 4,
    IntegratedWindowsAuthentication = Ntlm | Negotiate,
    Basic = 8,
    Anonymous = 32768,
}
```

Which rather answers the question...

How is IWA different to just Negotiate, seeing as Negotiate falls back to Ntlm, you wonder? The difference is to do with how the Ntlm messages are sent in the Http headers. Plain Ntlm messages will come through a `WWW-Authenticate` header that looks like `NTLM <some base 64 encoded data>`, whereas the Ntlm messages for the Negotiate protocol will be wrap up the NTLM data in additional protocol stuff. The web server may send many types of Authenticate headers, in case the client doesn't support one.

So, while Ntlm and Negotiate may both do Ntlm authentication, the wire protocol is different.

Comment: Another interesting point about Negotiate... While Negotiate could use either Kerberos or NTLM, if Windows _thinks_ Kerberos should work, it will not fall back to NTLM if it fails due to SPN mismatches or the like.

Answer (score 0):

IWA is what the feature is called by IIS

Negotiate is the name of the wire protocol used to implement it

Comment: That would be fine, but in the context of this enum what is the difference? Why do they have different flags value (6 vs 2). Setting it to Negotiate, I get the challenge cycle and my response `www-authenticate` header reads Negotiate and the second `www-authenticate` is Negotiate followed by the base64 ticket.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be much documentation on it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.authenticationschemes(v=vs.110).aspx

I would have to guess and say they are either identical, or the IWA option will defer to other system default settings such as IIS's configuration while forcing to Negotiate would override it. You could try using IWA and then changing it in IIS (with OWIN/Katana).

Note that its in System.Net Namespace not OWIN so you'll probably need to do some testing